# Graphical changes after gtk_widget_set_sensitive()

Tags: widget, gtk, documentation

I need to know what (graphically) happens to a button which is assigned to the "disabled" status with a *gtk_widget_set_sensitive()* function.

I am not the programmer but am documenting the behavior of a tool, built with Gtk+, which buttons are eventually disabled by the programmer by issuing that *gtk_widget_set_sensitive()* function (I am told). For my documentation, I need to emulate the visual result on the original icon once deactivated but I have no clue on what happens to it. It becomes brighter, blurry? desaturated? other?

Where can I find sources / hints on that?

what follow are caps of the two different (visual) statuses of such a button.

Enabled [image: active]

Disabled [image: disabled]

Answer (score 0):

This is the the documentation from Gtk [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOdMb.png).

> Insensitive widgets are “grayed out” and the user can’t interact with them. Insensitive widgets are known as “inactive”, “disabled”, or “ghosted” in some other toolkits.

How does disabled widget look like depends on the theme being used. You can install custom themes in Gnome desktop. I have two screenshot taken with "adwaita" and "adwaita-dark" theme.

[image: adwaita] 
[image: adwaita-dark]

Themes can be defined with CSS file. This is repo for adwaita theme. https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/tree/master/gtk/theme/Adwaita. You can search `button`, `insensitive` and `disabled` to find out what colors are being used.

To find the exact color used, you can find it
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-sensitive